# Use enum for switch case values in ghidra

Tags: ghidra

Is there a way in ghidra to change decompiled switch statement case values to their names?

I'm looking at a WndProc function, with a prototype of `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`. Inside the function are a number of switch statements based on the `msg` UINT, which ghidra calls `param_2`. The uint values are defined in `winuser.h`. I want to change all the spots `param_2` is compared in the decompilation so it uses the winuser.h names instead of the uint values, for example, change `if (param_2 != 0x100)` to `if (param_2 != WM_KEYDOWN)`, for all the `param_2` checks in a given function.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer here: [IDA Tips - Strings + Parameters](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/A+few+Ghidra+tips+for+IDA+users+part+2+strings+and+parameters/24848/)

In the disassembly, right click the constant, click `Set Equate...` and select the appropriate type. You may have to load (or create and load) the appropriate gdt file first.

Answer (score 1):

Besides manually changing each case, with some measure of success depending on the logic for the switch, the best way is to create an `enum` type (it must be sized correctly) with all the values you'd like to see, and then cast `param_2` to that `enum` type.

I don't do many Windows RE, so I'm not certain on how Ghidra has those values available currently, it might already exist in their windows libraries as an enum, though it might be a bunch of individual defines that you might to need to manually create into an `enum` to use like you're wanting.

Comment: Added some more details. The type is correct, the value is UINT, and the values are all #defines coming from winuser.h. Im wondering if theres an easy way to tell ghidra those come from winuser, and apply the defines appropriately